# SwiftUI - how to observe(.sink/ .onReceive) PassthroughSubject inside a View

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

If you encountered any of the next limitations while writing your app:

1. The type of your ViewModel or Model is Struct not Class. This way you will not be able to use ObservableObject + ObservedObject.
2. Also a second limitation is to avoid the use of Property Wrappers as: @Binding and @Published, in your Struct as they are harder to define as optional properties.
3. You don't want bidirectional biding like the one resulting from using @State + @Binding. You want to be **open** - allow others to observ changes, but be **closed** - don't allow for other to make changes (Delegate pattern in UIKit, published pattern in RXSwift, @StateObject in SwiftUI but only for Class).

You could consider the next solution.

Comment: This doesn’t replace the need for binding, in fact it removes the ability to make a two way connection, it doesn’t seem to solve anything. You can replace all that publishing and receiving code and just use the State wrapper with a one variable struct.

Comment: @loremipsum You don't always want a bidirectional biding, if you think about the SOLID principles sometimes is better just to observ the changes. Please read point 3.

Comment: Then you just make the variable “private (set)” . This still doesn’t solve anything

Comment: @loremipsum what I am trying to illustrate are the limitations of SwiftUI. In UIKit you have the delegate pattern, in this case if your VM is a Struct you need to have a property wrapper Binding or Binging<Value> for each callback. Due to the fact that you are not able to use mutating on VM that are Structs you are not able to use property or method DI. Property injection and method injection are nice to have because it allows you to set the delegate to nil, with SwiftUI you can only do this in the constructor.

Comment: @loremipsum consider you want to do the next:


`struct ViewModel {
    private(set) var textChangedDelegate: Binding<String>? = nil
    
    mutating func setTextChangedDelegate(_ delegate: Binding<String>?) {
        self.textChangedDelegate = delegate
    }
    
    func triggerUpdate() {
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.dateFormat = "YY/MM/dd-hh:mm:ss"
        let newStr = df.string(from: Date())
        textChangedDelegate?.wrappedValue = newStr
    }
}`

Comment: @loremipsum you are constrained to something like this:

`struct ViewModel {
    private(set) var textChangedDelegate: Binding<String>?
    
    init(textChangedDelegate: Binding<String>? = nil) {
        self.textChangedDelegate = textChangedDelegate
    }
    
    func triggerUpdate() {
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.dateFormat = "YY/MM/dd-hh:mm:ss"
        let newStr = df.string(from: Date())
        textChangedDelegate?.wrappedValue = newStr
    }
}`

Comment: Why do you need `Binding<String>?`? at all? `Binding` is only for SwiftUI views it should never be in a model. `Binding` is by definition a two-way connection...

Comment: The above code has multiple issues:
1. You are constrained to put all the optional bindings inside the constraint, if you have a few properties passed it is ok but if you have a lot of properties it breaks the principles of clean code.
2. It only constraints you to set up the Binding from another part of the app but it doesn't constrains you from updating it.

Comment: It sounds like you should look at the [basics](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-user-interface-state)  There isn't a question here just a bunch of statements about non existent issues. You can ask another question where there is a real problem that needs solving.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have a Struct as Model or ViewModel and you need to update your SwiftUI View here it is how to do just that with SwiftUI + Combine.

```
import Combine

struct ViewModel {

    var textChangedPublisher: AnyPublisher<String, Never> {
        textChangedSubject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    private let textChangedSubject = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()

    func triggerUpdate() {
        let newStr = DateFormatter().string(from: Date())
        textChangedSubject.send(newStr)
    }

}
```

And a screen:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    private let vieModel = ViewModel()
    @State private var title = "Let's start"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(title)
            Button.init("Show cuurent date") {
                vieModel.triggerUpdate()
            }
            .onReceive(vieModel.textChangedPublisher) { newValue in
                title = newValue
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Could make textChangedSubject public and get rid of the publisher.

Comment: From the SOLID principles, and real life use cases, you don't always need a bidirectional biding. Sometimes you need only to publish your changes. Please read the post again. Think of this as a StateObject but for Structs.